# JavaScript - Open a URL with window.open() and make a select all on the page opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using this code to open a URL in a new window. Is there possible to make a select all, like(CTRL + A does) to select return a determined text ?

I'm trying this, but i didn't succeed

For example, let's suppose if i used the google.com URL, and i want to select the text in footer. Like "Privacy", "Terms"... and so on

```
  var newWindow = window.open("URL HERE", '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");
  var range = newWindow.document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(newWindow.document.getElementsClassName('msg-info')[0]);
  newWindow.getSelection().addRange(range);
  newWindow.select();
```

Comment: Is the URL on the same origin as the page you're doing this on? (Same origin = same scheme [`http`, `https`], same host, same port.)

Comment: No, it's not, so I believe that should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the page you're opening is not on the same origin as the page you're doing this on, you can't do this. You don't have any access to the other page at all. (Same origin = same scheme [`http`, `https`], same host, same port.) This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

**If** the page is on the same origin, then you need to at least wait until the page has loaded, via a `load` handler or a `DOMContentLoaded` handler:

```
var newWindow = window.open("URL HERE", '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");
newWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var range = newWindow.document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(newWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('msg-info')[0]);
    newWindow.getSelection().addRange(range);
    newWindow.select();
});
```

(Note that it's `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementsClassName`. Or use `newWindow.document.querySelector('.msg-info')`.)